# Debugging a push method in Javascript with an object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, push

I am a beginner at js and have a project due by the end of day. I have to display an array with temps added and have set up an object to hold this array. My problem is that the message won't display and the for statement doesn't increment. When passed through both the var i and count come back undefined. I know there is a lot missing from this code but at this point I have tried to stream line it so that I can debug this issue. The date I will deal with later.

Here is my code:

```
var temps = [];

function process() {
    'use strict';

    var lowTemp = document.getElementById('lowTemp').value;
    var highTemp = document.getElementById('highTemp').value;

    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var inputDate = (new Date()).getTime();

    var temp = {
        inputDate : inputDate,
        lowTemp : lowTemp,
        highTemp : highTemp
    };

    var message = '';

    if (lowTemp == null) {
        alert ('Please enter a Low Temperature!');
        window.location.href = "temps.html";
    } else if (highTemp == null) {
        alert ('Please enter a High Temperature!');
        window.location.href = "temps.html";
    } else {
        lowTemp = parseFloat(lowTemp, 10);
        highTemp = parseFloat(highTemp, 10);
    }


    if (temp.value) {
        temps.push(temp.inputDate, temp.lowTemp, temp.highTemp)
        var message = '<h2>Temperature</h2><ol>';
        for (var i = 0, count = temps.length; i < count; i++) {
            message += '<li>' + temps[i] + '</li>'
        }   
        message += '</ol>';
            output.innnerHTML = message;
        }

    return false;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = process;
}

window.onload = init;


Here is my new code:

    var temps = [];

    function process() {
        'use strict';

        var lowTemp = document.getElementById('lowTemp').value;
        var highTemp = document.getElementById('highTemp').value;

        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var inputDate = (new Date()).getTime();

        var temp = {
            inputDate : inputDate,
            lowTemp : lowTemp,
            highTemp : highTemp
        };

        var message = '';

        if (lowTemp == null) {
            alert ('Please enter a Low Temperature!');
            window.location.href = "temps.html";
        } else if (highTemp == null) {
            alert ('Please enter a High Temperature!');
            window.location.href = "temps.html";
        } else {
            lowTemp = parseFloat(lowTemp, 10);
            highTemp = parseFloat(highTemp, 10);
        }


        if (temp.value) {
            temps.push(temp.inputDate, temp.lowTemp, temp.highTemp)
            var message = '<h2>Temperature</h2><ol>';
            for (var i = 0, count = temps.length; i < count; i++) {
                message += '<li>' + temps[i] + '</li>'
            }   
            message += '</ol>';
                output.innnerHTML = message;
            }

        return false;
    }

    function init() {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = process;
    }

    window.onload = init;
```

Comment: What is `temp.value`? You have never set this property to this object, so, your `if` will never return true, and the `temps.push` method will never be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some big issues with your code:

1. You should never compare anything to `NaN` directly. The correct comparison should be:

   ```
   if (isNaN(lowTemp)) {
   ```
2. You're using curly braces when not needed. You should remove both curly braces:

   ```
   {window.location.href = "temps.html";}
   ```
3. The function [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) expects only one parameter: the string to be converted. You're probably confusing it to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) which expects both the string and the radix of the conversion.
4. You're using the `temp`'s property `value`, but you have never setted it, so, the condition where you check if it exists will always return `false`, and the `push` method that you want to debug will never be called, since it's inside that `if` statement.
5. Finally, you're closing a `li` tag at the end, but you have never opened it. You should probably be closing the `ol` tag you have opened in the begining.

The rest of your code seems pretty OK for me.

---

Talking about debugging, you should read the [Google Chrome's Debugging Javascript Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/javascript/index).

Comment: Thanks for your help..I have corrected most of what you have mentioned and I had already caught the </li> error. I appreciate your help since I am very new at this.

Comment: @Julia if my answer was useful for you, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the `V`. Thanks! :)

Comment: your answer really helped me out but I am still not getting my var message to display and the for statement doesn't increment. When passed through both the var i and count come back undefined. So my question wasn't really answered. Is there a way to mark it to denote it was 1/2 answered?

Comment: @Julia There is another problem with your code: `temps.push(temp.inputDate, temp.lowTemp, temp.highTemp)`, you're passing three parameters to `push` method, and it expects only one.

Comment: Is there a way to push 3 values from an object (temps) into an array (temp)? That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: You could add the object itself, e.g: `temps.push(temp)`, and then use it as `temps[i].inputDate` etc. Or you could add a new object, like that: `temps.push({ inputDate: temp.inputDate, lowTemp: temp.lowTemp, highTemp: temp.highTemp });` and use it the same way. If you don't want to do that, you must use three different arrays, one for each property. @Julia

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I am going to do. I'll let you know how it turns out.